# bundle install not working in my project ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I don't know what I missed in my setup. I used rbenv for installing ruby. I learn it this page [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04). I successfully install ruby and rails. But the problem I have now is when I am in my current project. I did try this command inside my project `bundle install`, but I always get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /home/user90/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /home/user90/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/home/user90/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

same as doing this command in my current project `rails -v`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from bin/rails:5:in `<main>'
    3: from bin/rails:5:in `load'
    2: from /var/www/automated-leave-app/bin/spring:9:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /home/user90/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/home/user90/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

I also install `gem install bundler` in my current setup. Does the version matters? Here are my current setup version.

```
rails 5.2.0
ruby 2.5.1
gem 2.7.6
```

Comment: It should be `gem install bundler`.

Comment: I did that. It install but when I run `bundle install`. I get that error.

Comment: Please try this: `gem install bundler -v 1.17` and try again, if still does not work, please paste output of `which -a ruby`. Also try prepending bundle exec to your commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solutions for 'Cant find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle'](https://bundler.io/blog/2019/05/14/solutions-for-cant-find-gem-bundler-with-executable-bundle.html)

This is official doc on this error, you should have found this on top if you googled correctly. Gist is that there is **bundler version mismatch**, check `gemfile.lock` for bundler version and than install that version of `bundler`.

`gem install bundler -v VERSION_FROM_GEMFILE`

for example

`gem install bundler -v 1.17`

Comment: thank you sir. It save my whole week fixing that issue